# Oauth2Login for only specific urls

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to have an oauth2 configuration setup for login through Spring Security. But only for specific urls.

My security config looks as follows.

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .antMatcher("/secured/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
    .and()
    .oauth2Login()
    .clientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrationRepository())
    .authorizedClientService(authorizedClientService());
}
```

Basically I only want the oauth2Login to be trigger for urls that start with /secured. It seems to almost work, the only issue is whenever Spring trys to re-direct my session to google for authentication it triggers a 404.

The standard redirect for an oauth authentication should fire off to http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/google, which my application attempts to do, but it 404's.

I'm assuming the http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/google url is being blocked by some type of security config? But I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

I'm guessing I need to find the right combination of .permitAll() for any request going to "/oauth2/authorization/**"

I've tried this below.

```
    @Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .antMatcher("/secured/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth2/authorization/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
    .and()
    .oauth2Login()
    .clientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrationRepository())
    .authorizedClientService(authorizedClientService());
}
```

But that won't work.....does anyone see my issue? I have no other security config conflicting with this one, I'm at a bit of a loss.

Answer (score 1):

According to previous answer, the version with no lambda-style should look like this right?

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests
            .antMatchers("/secured/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .clientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrationRepository())
            .authorizedClientService(authorizedClientService());
}
```

If we want oauth2Login only for `"/secured/**"`, why have we to use `authenticated()` for `antMatcher("/secured/**")` and for `anyRequest()` (and not `permitAll()` for `anyRequest()`)?

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have updated my response with the correct configuration, using `permitAll()` as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The first step to understanding the issue here is understanding the difference between `http.antMatcher()` and `http.authorizeRequests()`.

Let's look at the following configuration.
(I am using the lambda-style configuration, available as of Spring Security 5.2, to make it more readable)

```java
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .antMatcher("/secured/**")
            .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login
                    .clientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrationRepository())
                    .authorizedClientService(authorizedClientService())
            );
}
```

Here, we are specifying that HTTP security will only be invoked when matching `"/secured/**"`.

In other words, the request will only be processed by the `SecurityFilterChain` if it matches `"/secured/**"`.

This is a problem because the `SecurityFilterChain` is what initiates the Authorization Request from `"/oauth2/authorization/google"`.

However, the `SecurityFilterChain` is not called because `"/oauth2/authorization/google"` does not match `"/secured/**"`.

Consider the following configuration instead.

```java
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .antMatchers("/secured/**").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
            )
            .oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login
                    .clientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrationRepository())
                    .authorizedClientService(authorizedClientService())
            );
}
```

Here, the HTTP security will be invoked for all requests.

However, only requests that match `"/secured/**"` will require the user to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @eleftheria-stein-kousathana brought me to another possible solution.

As stated it is important to know that the OAuth Endpoints won't called because the security config for them is bound to the `antMatcher()` call directly following the `HttpSecurity` object.

But as stated in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.x/reference/html/oauth2.html#oauth2login-advanced-redirection-endpoint) you can also change the baseUris of the `redirectionEndpoint` and the `authorizationEndpoint`

```java
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .antMatcher("/secured/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
    .and()
    .oauth2Login()
       //New Code Starting here
       .authorizationEndpoint()
          .baseUri("/secured/oauth2/authorization")
        .and()
        .redirectionEndpoint()
          .baseUri("/secured/oauth2/code/*")
        .and()
       //new code ending here
    .clientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrationRepository())
    .authorizedClientService(authorizedClientService());
}
```

Be sure to change the `redirectUriTemplate` of your `clientRegistration` and also the redirect uri configured at your AuthorizationServer

AND be sure to add the asterisk at the end of the `redirectionEndpoint.baseUri` ... that cost me some minutes to figure out what was wrong :-)