# Implement "oauth2Login()" and "httpBasic()" same page via MultiHttpSecurityConfig

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, spring-security-oauth2

If the user clicks /api/*, it will load the "formLogin()" page; otherwise loads "httpBasic()." This setup works fine. Below is its code.

```java
    @Configuration
        public class SecurityConfig {
    
        @Configuration
        @Order(1)
        public static class SpecialSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http
                    .antMatcher("/api/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .and()
                    .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/api/login");         
            }
            
            @Override
            public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
              web.ignoring().antMatchers("/", "/css/**");
            }
        }
    
        @Configuration
        public static class RegularSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .and()
                    .httpBasic();
            }
            
            @Override
            public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
              web.ignoring().antMatchers("/", "/css/**");
            }
        }
    
        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser("user")
                    .password("{noop}pass")
                    .roles("USER");
        }
    }
```

Now I want to remove  "formLogin()" and replace it with "oauth2Login()." After that, When I click the google link, it loads the "httpBasic()" login page.  If the user clicks google, it should go to the google login page. Please help me to fix this issue. Below is its code.

```java
        http
        .antMatcher("/api/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
        .loginPage("/api/oauth_login")
        .permitAll();
```

oauth_login.html

```html
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Social Login</h1>
    <p><a href="/oauth2/authorization/google">Google</a></p>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying that requests that match `"/api/**"` should be secured by `SpecialSecurityConfig` using OAuth 2 login and all the other requests should be secured by `RegularSecurityConfig` using HTTP basic.

Since `"/oauth2/authorization/google"` does not match `"/api/**"` it is secured using HTTP basic.

One option is to change the base URI used for authorization requests to start with `"/api/"` (the default is `"/oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}"`).

You will likely also want to customize the `loginProcessingUrl` and the `authorizationRequestResolver`.

```java
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .antMatcher("/api/**")
        .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
            .loginProcessingUrl("/api/login/oauth2/code/*")
            .loginPage("/api/oauth_login")
            .authorizationEndpoint(ae -> ae
                .baseUri("/api/oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}")
                .authorizationRequestResolver(getAuthorizationRequestResolver())
            )
        );
}

private OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver getAuthorizationRequestResolver() {
    return new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(
        this.clientRegistrationRepository,
        "/api/oauth2/authorization");
}
```

You would then also update your login form

```
<p><a href="/api/oauth2/authorization/google">Google</a></p>
```

Comment: I changed the Html code as you suggest. After that, when I click the google link, it redirects to the same page.

Comment: @Dinesh Did you update the `baseUri` in your security configuration to start with "/api"?

Comment: After adding  "baseUri("/api/oauth2/authorization/")" I'm able to load google login page. After sign in I'm getting Whitelabel Error Page page with url
http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google?state=55Ct1GEytBC9Iiq----
any idea?

Comment: You probably want to set the loginProcessingUrl and the authorizationRequestResolver as well. I've updated my answer to include those.

Comment: After adding those changes still I got the same error. 

Resource not found 
Completed 404 NOT_FOUND

Comment: It seems like the redirect-uri is still set to "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/google". Make sure you are configuring this to the updated value "{baseUrl}/api/login/oauth2/code/google" in both the client registration in you Spring App and on the Google authorization server.

Comment: Thank you @Eleftheria Stein-Kousathana

Comment: From what's dependency OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver is come form?

Answer (score 1):

Now I able to load the google login page. After adding the credential, the page redirects to the Whitelabel Error Page.

Oauth2 code

```
http
            .antMatcher("/api/**")
            .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2.loginProcessingUrl("/api/login/oauth2/code/*")
                    .loginPage("/api/oauth_login").permitAll()
                    .authorizationEndpoint(a -> a.baseUri("/api/oauth2/authorization")
                            .authorizationRequestResolver(                                    
                                    getAuthorizationRequestResolver())
                            )
            );
```

ERROR ->

2021-03-11 15:02:53.319 DEBUG 11762 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login/oauth2/code/google?state=Ds-x92t6fpHo8BINK_xYba3fpidheKQSHBaTdctOPRE%3D&code=4%2F0AY0e-g6i-tfqlpBREW45ufRPQEOu-aM7VjIf7VzKOBVMSXrvLkaxB5U2A72dAOxxEUnN1Q&scope=email+profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&authuser=0&hd=wearenoetic.com&prompt=consent", parameters={masked}

2021-03-11 15:02:53.321 DEBUG 11762 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], ServletContext resource [/]]

2021-03-11 15:02:53.346 DEBUG 11762 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found

2021-03-11 15:02:53.346 DEBUG 11762 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND

2021-03-11 15:02:53.348 DEBUG 11762 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error?state=Ds-x92t6fpHo8BINK_xYba3fpidheKQSHBaTdctOPRE%3D&code=4%2F0AY0e-g6i-tfqlpBREW45ufRPQEOu-aM7VjIf7VzKOBVMSXrvLkaxB5U2A72dAOxxEUnN1Q&scope=email+profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&authuser=0&hd=wearenoetic.com&prompt=consent", parameters={masked}

2021-03-11 15:02:53.349 DEBUG 11762 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)

2021-03-11 15:02:53.373 DEBUG 11762 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]

2021-03-11 15:02:53.374 DEBUG 11762 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404

Comment: After adding below code I'm able to solve this issue
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.redirect-uri={baseUrl}/api/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}

Answer (score 0):

I refer the below URL and modify my code

[Oauth2Login for only specific urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62584724/oauth2login-for-only-specific-urls)

```
http 
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()        
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
        .loginPage("/api/oauth_login")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/api/home")
        .permitAll();
```

Normal URLs(other than /api/*) also load google login page.

Answer (score 0):

Disable basic login and form login. Sample security config would look like;

```
 .formLogin()
                .disable()
            .httpBasic()
                .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/oauth2/**")
                    .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                .and()
            .oauth2Login()
                .authorizationEndpoint()
                    .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize")
                    .and()
                .redirectionEndpoint()
                .baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*")
```

Call this endpoint from the frontend (Google/Facebook button should be linked to the below link)
http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorize/{provider}?redirect_uri=<redirect_uri_after_login>

Follow this [guide](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-2/). This is exactly what are you looking for.